# Detect Device - My Mac ( Designed for iPad )

Tags: ios, swift, macos

Is there any to check app is running on My Mac (Designed for iPad)?

These options don't work:

```
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersionString.contains("Mac OS X") {
    print("Mac Designed for iPad ")
} else {
    // Running on an iPad or other iOS device
    // Perform iPad-specific tasks or UI adjustments
}

if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .mac {
    print("app is running on mac")
} else {
    print("iPad")
}

#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst) {
    print("mac Catalyst")
}
#endif
```